# Pandas: add a new column with one single value at the last row of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My request is simple but I am stuck and do not know why... my dataframe looks like this:

```
   price  time  
0      1     3    
1      3     6    
2      4     7
```

What I need to do is to add a new column `mkt` with only one value equal to 10 at the last row (in my example index = 2). What I have tried:

```
df.mkt=''
df.mkt.loc[-1] =10
```

But when I want to see again my dataframe the last row is not updated... I know the answer must be simple but I am stuck? Any idea? thanks!

Comment: No, you should specify both axis *inside* `.loc`. So `df.loc[len(df)-1,'mkt'] = 10`

Comment: Also  using -1, would work with `.iloc`, not `loc`, which looks for exact matches on the content of the indices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [at](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) function:

```
df.mkt = ''
df.at[-1, 'mkt'] = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pd.Series:

```
df['mkt'] = [''] * (len(df)-1) +[10]
```